# Express.js : regex in route

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, routes

I want to get a value in my url.

My url is like :

> host/:value.schema

I want to get value.

Exemple :

> host/horse.schema value = horse

I have another route without .schema:

> host/:value

Exemple :

> host/horse value = horse

How tell Express to make the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
app.get('/:value.:schema?', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params);
});
```

You'll receive this:

```
http://localhost:3000/horse        { value: 'horse', schema: undefined }
http://localhost:3000/horse.schema { value: 'horse', schema: 'schema' }
```

Comment: It works. but is it possible to do that with regex ?